# csproj <Content> with CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" is invalid

Tags: .net-core, csproj

The following is from my csproj. I'm getting an error that "PreserveNewest" is a wrong attribute value. I'm not sure what do I need to change it to without changing the behavior of the project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="nlog.config" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it will build fine, but is a known issue with intellisense in versions of Rider before October 2019:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-20183

According to the history it's fixed in 2019.3 EAP1 (193.4778.12) and above.

The latest version available at time of writing appears to be 2019.3 EAP7.
https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/eap/